# VPN and software

Tags: vpn

If I use [Hide.me](https://hide.me/en/software/android) VPN does it route all traffic of software such as Adobe through the VPN?

If not, what VPN or software can I use to route all traffic of software used such as Adobe through the VPN?

Windows operating system, please.

Answer (score 3):

A *virtual private **network*** VPN and routing in general works on the network layer. Therefore, it doesn't care about the applications, like e.g. proxies would do.

Technically a VPN can route all traffic or specific networks through the tunnel. VPN services for privacy usually route all traffic, but could leave routes to directly connected local networks. A corporate VPN could add routes only to internal networks or route everything. But never only certain applications.

Comment: Thank you for answering. You're saying then that VPNs make sure all traffic including all applications such as Adobe would be routed through the VPN, so because of that, hide me VPN should be safe to use with Adobe?

Comment: What is your actual question? What problem do you want to solve? Why are you specifically asking about Adobe? And what do you mean by "hide me VPN"?

Comment: Thank you for answering. Hide me VPN is https://hide.me/en/ . I'm asking about Adobe because the software connects to the internet and I want the traffic to be routed through the VPN. Do you know if Hide me VPN or any other VPN does that?

Comment: As explained in this answer, every VPN does that - otherwise it's not a VPN.